# If there is std::greater, why is it called std::less and not std::lesser?

Tags: c++, std, language-design

This apparently looks like a grammatical (and funny?) question but I hope it is not.

I seriously wonder why we have [std::greater](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) if we don't have `std::lesser` (instead we have [std::less](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less))?  Doesn't it make sense to have either `greater` and `lesser` or `great` and `less`?  I ask this question because I pretty much mess it up every single time and need to Google it.

Is there some naming convention that the standard follows?

Comment: In English, we say "greater than" or "less than", not "lesser than" (examples: "5 is greater than 4" and "4 is less than 5"). I don't have any evidence to back my next claim up, but I think it's reasonable to conclude that these type names were chosen based on the common English phrasing.

Comment: Mr. Downvoter, care to comment?  MCVE, opinion-based, spam, what?

Comment: Use std::max and std::min to return the "greater" or "lesser" of two alternatives.

Comment: @jcarpenter, yes, but it is not replacable _always_.

Comment: For one, STL predates C++'s standardization... Most likely, nobody bothered to raise a point about the name, when it was being standardized, the name stuck. Years passed, heaps of code were built on it, and we now have probably billions of code sitting on your "grammar debate", However, even if anyone wrote a proposal to change the name, that is unlikely to make it through today as far as `std::` is concerned. Maybe `std2::`, `std3::`, ...?

Comment: Sometimes people will leave a downvote for questions that they don't believe belong on the site. I think it's a bit cowardly to do so without leaving a comment. Unfortunately I don't think this question is answerable.

Comment: @MarkRansom The problem is sometimes if you leave a comment and downvote, people revenge downvote. "Either comment or downvote but not both" - common advice around here.

Comment: @NirFriedman I see your point, but I still think a downvote without explanation is unhelpful. And being helpful is the reason I come here. If you can't leave the comment then don't vote. I guess I can afford my opinion though, a downvote isn't going to make much difference to me.

Comment: @Cornstalks I guess you may as well put that as the answer, I think it's the best answer possible.

Comment: Related, and interesting: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/391839/why-is-the-opposite-of-greater-than-less-than

Comment: It is just betterer this way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is indeed a grammatical question (or rather a question about the English language), not about programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say, and this is really just informed *speculation,* that the authors of the standard made an explicit choice to go one way rather than the other. English, in its near-infinite capacity for confusing people, has many ways for expressing the same idea

```
a is GREATER than b   =>   a is the GREATER value
a is LESS    than b   =>   a is the LESSER  value
```

However, since the *intent* of `std::greater` and `std::less` is to return a Boolean value indicating whether the related condition is true, the left-hand column above is the right way to go. If instead it *returned* the greater or lesser value, it would be more apt to use the right hand column.

In fact, if you look at the ISO standard (`C++11 20.8.5 Comparisons /4 and /5`), you'll see how they're defined (slightly reformatted):

```
template <class T> struct greater {
    bool operator()(const T& x, const T& y) const;
    typedef T first_argument_type;
    typedef T second_argument_type;
    typedef bool result_type;
};                                                   // operator() returns x > y.
template <class T> struct less {
    bool operator()(const T& x, const T& y) const;
    typedef T first_argument_type;
    typedef T second_argument_type;
    typedef bool result_type;
};                                                   // operator() returns x < y.
```

Those comment sections would clearly be read as "returns x is ***greater*** than y" and "returns x is ***less*** than y".

Comment: It boils down to whether we are talking about nouns or whether we are talking about adjectives.